# Objective-C: Flooring to 3 decimals correctly

Tags: objective-c, math, rounding, floor

I am trying to floor a float value to the third decimal. For example, the value 2.56976 shall be 2.569 not 2.570. I searched and found answers like these:

[floor double by decimal place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273179/floor-double-by-decimal-place)

Such answers are not accurate. For example the code:

```
double value = (double)((unsigned int)(value * (double)placed)) / (double)placed
```

can return the `value - 1` and this is not correct. The multiplication of value and placed `value * (double)placed)` could introduce something like: 2100.999999996. When changed to unsigned int, it becomes 2100 which is wrong (the correct value should be 2101). Other answers suffer from the same issue. In Java, you can use `BigDecimal` which saves all that hassels.

(Note: of course, rounding the 2100.9999 is not an option as it ruins the whole idea of flooring to "3 decimals correctly")

Comment: Doesn't the solution I gave in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158903/objective-c-floorf-returns-wrong-value?lq=1 help here? You need to bump up the digit _after_ the one you want to floor by half before flooring.

Comment: You can also use `NSDecimalNumber` which can represent decimal numbers with up to 38 digits precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to consider a solution involving NSString and it worked like a charm. Here is the full method:

```
- (float) getFlooredPrice:(float) passedPrice {

    NSString *floatPassedPriceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", passedPrice];
    NSArray *floatArray = [floatPassedPriceString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *fixedPart = [floatArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *decimalPart = @"";
    if ([floatArray count] > 1) {
        NSString *decimalPartWhole = [floatArray objectAtIndex:1];
        if (decimalPartWhole.length > 3) {
            decimalPart = [decimalPartWhole substringToIndex:3];
        } else {
            decimalPart = decimalPartWhole;
        }
    }
    NSString *wholeNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", fixedPart, decimalPart];

    return [wholeNumber floatValue];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    double value = 1.23456;
    double val3;
    val3 = floor(1000.0 * value + 0.0001) * 0.001; // add 0.0001 to "fix" binary representation problem
    printf("val3 is %.8f; the error is %f\n", val3, 1.234 - val3);
}
```

this prints out

```
val3 is 1.23400000; the error is 0.000000
```

If there are any residual errors, it comes about from the fact that floating point numbers cannot necessarily be represented exactly - the idea behind BigDecimal and things like that is to work around that in a very explicit way (for example by representing a number as its digits, rather than a binary representation - it's less efficient, but maintains accuracy)

Comment: Well, this also doesn't work. For example, I used value = 2.099. The multiplication 1000.0 * value gives 2098.99997711182 which when floored gives 2098 (not correct)

Comment: @A.Shatou The reason is that `2.099` is actually stored as `2.09899997711182` for the same reasons as given in your previous question.

Comment: That is odd - on my machine (64 bit Mac), I get 2.09900000 when I start with 2.099 . The problem with the "floor" function is that it will really round down even if you're just the tiniest bit off. If you could tolerate "rounding up" when the number is within 0.000001 of the next number up, it becomes more robust. What platform are you using (bit depth)? I have updated my answer with a suggested "fix"; but really the `floor` function has a nasty discontinuity and you won't get around that easily...

Comment: @Floris I am building for iOS simulator. I know that and I think I shall consider preparing the date correct from the start.

Comment: OK good luck with that @A.Shatou. I wonder if there is a `long double` type on your platform to make the above code work. What is `sizeof(double)` in your compiler?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, the value 2.56976 shall be 2.569 not 2.570

Solution is has simple as that :

```
double result = floor(2.56976 * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
```

I don't know why you search complication... this works perfectly, doesn't need to pass by some `unsigned int` or other `+ 0.0001` or whatever.

**Important note :**

```
NSLog(@"%.4f", myDouble);
```

Actually do a round on your variable. So it's improper to believe you can floor with a `%.Xf`